# Stopping a php file execution after sometime

Tags: php, websocket, web-development-server

I have a 2 php files. One run_server.php as follows:

```
<?php
echo "Initializing";
shell_exec("php -q server.php &");
echo "finishing !";
?>
```

And in server.php, I am running a server and 2 clients as follows:

```
<?php
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
ini_set('set_time_limit', 10);
$Command = 'commands.txt';  
exec(" parallel -j 8 < $Command");  
?>
```

Commands.txt is as follows:

```
code/./server &
clients/./O 180.215.167.197 &
clients/./X 180.215.167.197 &
```

It is a bot program where I run a server and 2 clients from server.php file which is called by run_server.php. My problem is that the line

```
shell_exec("php -q server.php &");
```

never returns even after the execution of server and clients are complete. I tried putting a

```
max_execution_time / set_time_limit
```

but no help. Is there some way in which I can forcefully return to run_server.php from server.php after a fixed period of time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `header();`, for example.

```
<?php
echo "Initializing";
shell_exec("php -q server.php &");
header('location:http://mydomain.com/server.php');
echo "finishing !";
?>
```

Comment: I checked via netstat -ntlp that the server is no longer running still the code does not return and stops execution of server.php file ? No help with header either. Any other suggestions ?